# Как в React.js вывести столько div сколько пришло в props компоненту?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Как вывести заданное количество (amount) div-ов в компоненте React? Например пришло число 10 в amount - выводим 10 одинаковых div.

```
interface ISomeComponent {
   amount: number;
};

const SomeComponent:React.FC<ISomeComponent> = ({ amount }) => {

   return (
     <div></div> * amount
   );

}
```

Comment: `return new Array(10).map(() => <div></div>)`

Comment: @entithat только, наверно, new Array(10)

Comment: @hlearn, да-да, на автомате написал. Хотел `Array.from({ length: 10 })`

Comment: @entithat спасибо! Сделал вот так: `Array.from(Array(amount).keys()).map(i => ( <div /> ))}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 return (
    <>
      {Array.from(Array(amount).keys()).map(i => (
        <div />
      ))}
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение: принимает любое число и на всякий случай обработал случаи с 0 или undefined.

```
interface ISomeComponent {
  amount?: number;
}

export const SomeComponent: React.FC<ISomeComponent> = ({ amount }) => (
  <>
{ amount ? Array.from({ length: amount })
   .map((_, index) => <div key={`${index}/amount`} />) : null }
</>
);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]